# Has Microsoft removed the zoom for results view in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I have just upgraded to SSMS 2018 and have noticed that the results text seems much smaller and is hard to read from further away.

I have tried changing the font size however it only changed the font size of the query pane.

Maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: Do you mean in the Result to Grid pane? I don't recall that that has ever had a Zoom feature.It was only the query and messages pane that did.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the SSMS Tools menu, choose Options. 
Then in the search box type 'FON', choose 'Font and Colors' and from the drop down list labeled 'Show settings for : ' choose 'Grid Results'. 
Enlarge the font size. Restart SSMS and your view will be much better.

[image]

Comment: Explaining how you get to that menu might help the OP if they aren't familiar with the menus and panes within SSMS.

Comment: Thank you  @Larnu for your observation. It was just before lunch, when I answered.

Comment: Thanks, Completely overlooked that drop down menu

Comment: Thanks to Microsoft for making the default font for the grid results `7`.

Comment: Thank you! It is very puzzling why Microsoft didn't just simply provide a zoom option (like that for the Query Pane) since that seems logical.

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl-T to change the output of the query window to text. Rerun your query and then Ctrl-scrollwheel will zoom both the query and results. Not as nice as the grid, but it's a quick & easy solution when screen sharing, for example.

[image: Zoom results]

Answer (score -3):

Another method is to click anywhere on the query or results window. Then hold down the "CTRL" and scroll your mouse button up or down. This changes the size of the text.

Comment: This does not work in the Results pane, only the Query pane

Comment: Old I know, but don't be so hasty to dismiss this suggestion: Press Ctrl-T to change to text output, rerun the query and then this works a treat. Good for quick zooming while screen sharing. I hate the fact you have to go into Options to change the grid view, so this is a nice compromise.